# SmartGWT : CalendarEvent not displaying at proper place

Tags: calendar, smartgwt

I am facing one issue on SmartGWT `Calendar` ojects doesn't show `CalendarEvents` on its proper place I have two events that needs to be displayed

EVENT ID ::: 1  :: START DATE :: Mon Mar 11 16:30:00 IST 2013  :: END DATE :: Mon Mar 11 19:00:00 IST 2013

EVENT ID ::: 2  :: START DATE :: Mon Mar 11 20:00:00 IST 2013  :: END DATE :: Mon Mar 11 23:06:00 IST 2013

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRbBh.png) Shows : Calendar Event Showing details for Event 2 but is place on wrong place

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2X5g.png) Shows : Calendar Event Showing details for Event 1 but the time the event is set on is of Event 1

I am also attaching my source code:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
    criteria.addCriteria("truckId", "10");

    calendar.setShowDayView(false);
    calendar.setShowMonthView(false);
    calendar.setShowWeekView(true);
    calendar.setRowHeight(40);
    calendar.setDisableWeekends(false);
    calendar.setTimeFormatter(TimeFormatter.TOSHORT24HOURTIME);
    calendar.setDataSource(DataSource.get(LOAD_DMI));  
    calendar.invalidateCache();

    calendar.fetchData(criteria, new DSCallback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void execute(DSResponse response, Object rawData, DSRequest request) 
        {
            try
            {
                Record[] recordList = response.getData();
                record = new CalendarEvent();                   
                int temp = 1;
                calendarEvnt = new CalendarEvent[recordList.length];
                for(int k=0; k<recordList.length; k++)
                {
                    record.setEventId(temp);
                    record.setName(recordList[k].getAttribute("customerName"));
                    record.setDescription(recordList[k].getAttribute("truckName"));
                    record.setStartDate(recordList[k].getAttributeAsDate("scheduledPickUpDateAndTime"));
                    record.setEndDate(recordList[k].getAttributeAsDate("scheduledDropOffDateAndTime"));

                    calendarEvnt[k] = new CalendarEvent(record.getEventId(), record.getName(), record.getDescription(), record.getStartDate(), record.getEndDate());

                    temp++;
                }
                System.out.println("CALENDER EVENT Size ::: "+calendarEvnt.length);
                calendar.setData(calendarEvnt);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    calendar.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar set `setEventAutoArrange(false)` may solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I've stumbled upon this, I did try `setEventAutoArrange(false)`, that call solved the problem until I noticed that if setEventAutoArrange is set to false calendar item can't show events which share the same start and end time. I'm not sure why smartgwt renders events as shown by OP. However I've found out once the datasource fetch is done if you call `calendar.markForRedraw();` in the `DSCallback` the problem goes away and you don't need `setEventAutoArrange(false)` and calander can render all events with no problems.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

-- Edit --

It seems that this does not work on all cases.